# How to detrend time series in python (to remove outliers)

Tags: python, time-series, outliers

I have a time series that trends in a direction. Because of this, it makes standard deviation not a very good tool to analyse the data. Is there a way i can "detrend" or flatten the data, so i can do outlier analysis easier?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120270

Answer (score 3):

So for anyone else that is looking to do the same thing here is what i've found works for what i am trying to do...

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def flatten_data(x, y):
    lr = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
    slope = lr.coef_[0][0]
    y_int = lr.intercept_[0]
    flattened = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        expected_val = slope * x[i] + y_int
        flattened.append(y[i] - expected_val)
    return flattened
```

This will do linear regression of your data. And then just iterate through your data points and calculate how far away each point is from the line of best fit. This should give you a flattened version of your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use R for this, there are plenty of packages supporting detrending a time series (depending on the trend you have, additive/multiplicative). You can use time series decomposition techniques such as *stl* [1], *decompose* [2], and *stR* [3]. Once, you decompose the time series into seasonality, trend, and the remainder, for the detrending purposes, you can exclude the trend component (use seasonality + remainder)

Also, if you want to stick with Python, follow the [4] to decompose the time series, and exclude the trend component from the time series as mentioned above.

Additionally, if you are interested in stabilising the variance of the data, i suggest you to apply log transformation to your time series (just take the log of the time series)

Hope this helps.

[1] https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/stl

[2] https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/decompose.html

[3] https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stR/vignettes/stRvignette.html

[4] https://machinelearningmastery.com/decompose-time-series-data-trend-seasonality/